Проблема с кнопками discord.py (interaction.user)
После загрузки бота в виртуальную машину, появилась проблема

user = interaction.user
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'Button' object has no attribute 'user'

Никак не могу понять почему она появляется. Считает interaction за button
Кусок кода:
class supportButton(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self, quest, member, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.quest = quest
        self.member = member
    @discord.ui.button(label="Открыть обсуждение по данному вопросу",style=discord.ButtonStyle.gray, row=1)
    async def first_button_callback(self, button: discord.ui.Button, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        user = interaction.user


Попробуйте после self сначала указать interaction, а потом button:
async def first_button_callback(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
    user = interaction.user

